# Xcode giving me errors to do with the account team not working

Tags: xcode

Errors:

1. > error: No account for team "2ZDN69KUUV". Add a new account in the
   >   Accounts preference pane or verify that your accounts have valid
   >   credentials. (in target 'SpriteKitWatchFace WatchKit App')
2. > error: No profiles for
   >   'com.highcaffeinecontent.SpriteKitWatchFace.watchkitapp' were found:
   >   Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles
   >   matching 'com.highcaffeinecontent.SpriteKitWatchFace.watchkitapp'. (in
   >   target 'SpriteKitWatchFace WatchKit App')
3. > error: No account for team "2ZDN69KUUV". Add a new account in the
   >   Accounts preference pane or verify that your accounts have valid
   >   credentials. (in target 'SpriteKitWatchFace WatchKit Extension')
4. > error: No profiles for
   >   'com.highcaffeinecontent.SpriteKitWatchFace.watchkitapp.watchkitextension'
   >   were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning
   >   profiles matching
   >   'com.highcaffeinecontent.SpriteKitWatchFace.watchkitapp.watchkitextension'.
   >   (in target 'SpriteKitWatchFace WatchKit Extension')

I've been getting these error messages for a while now and I haven't come to any conclusion on how to fix it! please help!!!!

the error messages shown above are all from when I try to load the app onto my phone.

what I've done so far is really just looking at the targeted area and consistently playing around with the signing section of the project with no prevail. it seems that when I have it set to open in the emulator it turns on and starts downloading the project but then it come up with this message

> error: No profiles for 'com.highcaffeinecontent.SpriteKitWatchFace.watchkitapp.watchkitextension' >were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning >profiles matching 'com.highcaffeinecontent.SpriteKitWatchFace.watchkitapp.watchkitextension'>. (in target 'SpriteKitWatchFace WatchKit Extension')

and then stops downloading in the emulator.

thanks in advance

finn

Comment: Hello @finn-worchurst. Please write the Error message. Posting image isn't convenient and reliable way to post the code.

Comment: retyped it but don't know how to put in actual code format on here. really sorry

Comment: Now, please let us know why you got this errors and what you have done so far.

Comment: Hi, have you tried looking where the "2ZDN69KUUV" team is mentioned in the xcodeproject?